# Apache Camel jms breadcrumbId

Tags: apache-camel

How can I generate jms breadcrumbId using Apache Camel?

I can't find proper source for it and I will be very thankful for something.

Comment: Here is the documentation: [Apache Camel: MDC Logging](http://camel.apache.org/mdc-logging.html)